# How to display multiple images after uploading them?

Tags: php, file-upload

I looked up for multiple file uploading script, so I stumbled on this: http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL I know this is an old post, but it's working very well. I deleted SQL part because I don't need it. So as you look at script, it only uploads multiple files to server, and I tried ti display uploaded images, like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir="../img/full-size";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }       
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
        echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";
        echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This works, but only for one Image, not array. Any help?

Comment: Why so much `}` at the end?

Comment: What is output at the moment?

Comment: You are iterating over `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']` so in case you have several images this key doesn't exist, you need to iterate over `$_FILES`

Comment: print_r($_FILES); what it gives?

Comment: Output is just one image two times

Comment: O.O @EmirDupovac that means multiple images is stored in your folder but while displaying it shows one image right?

Comment: @RakeshShetty it gives this: "Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => logo-small.png [1] => logo-small-invert.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpE77.tmp "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you said:

> Output is just one image two times

Sure it is so, because you did this:

```
for each uploaded image
    move image somewhere
end for
if no errors
    show 2 same images (it will be last images shown 2 times)
end if
```

You do this part:

```
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
    echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";
    echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";
}
```

not in for, but right after it. Your code output last uploaded image 2 times.

You need to put output in `for in` loop (updated code with array of images links):

```
$images = array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
    $desired_dir="../img/full-size";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }  
        $images[] ="<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>"; //  <----- there    
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}

foreach($images as $image) {
     echo $image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, and thanks for good explanation. And how could I output outside the loop, because I need it in special div?

Comment: Add array and push images paths to this array and after that loop through it array

Comment: @EmirDupovac update your answer with new code better

Comment: Yes it did, it works great, thanks alot! Just one question, echo $image; works great, but I tried this: foreach($images as $image) { $write_content ="<div class='row'>" . $image . " </div>"; }, So if I put it in variable it shows only one image again.

Comment: @EmirDupovac You have to use `.=` instead of `=` symbol. `=` means to reassign value, `.=` means add to string.

Comment: No, that's just HTML that i wanted to output, look at it this way: $variable = "this is text" . $image . "more text"; and now it should put images between, but it shows only one image.

Comment: You using this: `$write_content ="<div class='row'>" . $image . " </div>";` in a loop. Each time loop firing contents of `$write_content` is rewrited. Right after loop `$write_content` var contents only code with one image. You need this: `$write_content .="<div class='row'>" . $image . " </div>";`. After loop variable will contain all images. Just echo it and images will be outputed

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't understand at first. It works perfectly now, thanks a lot, you were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to display images from your folder after uploading, so try this:

Remove this code :

```
if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
        echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";
        echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";

    }
```

And add this

```
if(empty($error)){

    $files = glob("../img/full-size/*.*");
    for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {

      $num = $files[$i];
      echo '<img src="'.$num.'" align="absmiddle" /> ';
      print substr(substr($num,6,100),0,-4);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just try ,*

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir="ne_img";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir");
                chmod("$desired_dir", 0755);       // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name) ;
                $files_name[] = $file_name;
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }       
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        if(is_array($files_name))
        {
            foreach($files_name as $file_name)
            {
                echo "<img src='" . $desired_dir . '/' . $file_name . "'>";
            }
        }


    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If image of uploaded name has same name as one of existing images this will not work.