# get images from folder based on variables

Tags: php, image, upload

I try to get all the images from a folder with this code.
the result is not correct because the code echo a "/" too much (just like below)

Someone please help!

```
        $dirname = 'uploads/'.$email.'/'.$product_id.'/';
        $images = glob($dirname."*");

        foreach($images as $image) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
        }


<img src="uploads/test@test.com//52">
```

This is the desired result:

```
<img src="uploads/test@test.com/52/">
```

---

This is the final result..

Thank to Rakesh Shetty thank you!

```
$product_id = $row['product_id'];
$dirname = 'uploads/'.$email.'/'.$product_id.'/';

$files = glob($dirname."*.*");

print_r($files); // check what you get

    for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++){
      $num = $files[$i];
      echo '<img src="'.$num.'" /> ';
}

print_r($files);
```

Comment: Don't know why the `glob()` returns paths with double `/` but you can fix it by using `str_replace('//', '/', $image)`

Comment: I had checked your code is worked for me.

Comment: Could you please check whether the path contains all values like $email and $product_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538708/how-to-display-multiple-images-after-uploading-them/23539107#23539107)

```
$dirname = 'uploads/'.$email.'/'.$product_id.'/';

$files = glob($dirname."*.*");

print_r($files); // check what you get


    for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {

      $num = $files[$i];
      echo '<img src="'.$num.'" /> ';


    }
```

Comment: try to print_r($files); what you get?

Comment: also according to you $product_id is empty i think please check

Comment: I need to remove one * from glob($dirname.".*"); otherwise the code won't work.. the print_r result :

Array ( [0] => uploads/info@ixxes.com//. [1] => uploads/info@ixxes.com//.. )

Comment: your $product_id variable is empty. why? try echoing the variable wheather it get the value or not